# Save high-res image html5/threejs-canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, data-uri

I found and edited below code to save my html5 canvas as a .png-image. The canvas is generated by Three.js/Potree.
This code works perfectly. But, I want a higher resolution image as an output. Usually, the THREEjs renderer is sized according to the clients browser size. I have already manually enlarged it to 3000x2000. This edit will give a higher-resolution image, but when increasing more no effects are visible anymore.

Is there a simple (I'm not that into javascript..) workaround for downloading a high-resolution output image?

*At first, the images are just for me. No user needs to download it or needs to pass it onto the server. Although, if its a neat solution, I'd like to give the user the possibility to save their image as well.*

```
function saveAsImage() {
    var strDownloadMime = "image/octet-stream";
    //alert("function saveimage")
    var imgData, imgNode;

    try {
        var strMime = "image/png";
        imgData = viewer.renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime);

        saveFile(imgData.replace(strMime, strDownloadMime), "test.png");

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
    }

}

var saveFile = function (strData, filename) {
    //alert("savefilefunction");
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
        document.body.appendChild(link); //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = strData;
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link); //remove the link when done
    } else {
        location.replace(uri);
    }
}
```

THREE Renderer settings:

```
    let width = 3000;
    let height= 2000;

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({premultipliedAlpha: false, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
```

Comment: have you ever tried to save image from context menu(right click menu)?